# async calls inside get accessor - is it good practice?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, asynchronous, properties

I have a window that shows customer infomation.
when the window loads, I call `LoadCustomer()` method from the constructor which loads the customer information from the database asynchorously, which sets the `CurrentCustomer` property.
and then the UI is updated because it is bound to the `CurrentCustomer`.

```
private void LoadCustomer(Guid customerID)
{           
   var customerContext = new CustomerContext();

   var customerQuery = customerContext.GetCustomersQuery()
                                         .Where(e => e.CustomerID == customerID);

   customerContext.Load(customerQuery, 
      loadOperation =>
      {
         CurrentCustomer = loadOperation.Entities.SingleOrDefault();
      }, null);
}
```

The senior programmer has told me that it's better to put this logic inside CurrentCustomer's get accessor, because then

- the calls to the database will use lazy loading, and
- the refactoring would be easier.

Is it good practice to put async database calls inside property's get accessor?

Comment: Loads do not belong in a *getter*. Side effects would not be anticipated reading the code. It is more likely that the context will be moved around, so best to keep it all readable. Sometimes *senior* just means *old*. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generally, it's not.**

Usually if getting something would involves doing something else expensive as well, you should use a full getter method just for this purpose:

```
public object GetSomething() { }

// accessing code
var value = obj.GetSomething();
```

This signifies that getting that something isn't free... Compare to:

```
var value = obj.Something;
```

This looks more like a normal value assignment hiding the dangerous async call going on behind the scene which, IMO is a bad idea.

**But as with everything else... *it depends* on other parts in the whole architecture as well.**

If the whole purpose of the object is to abstract away lots of asynchronous calls using property (such as the case with Linq2Sql or Entity Framework entities) then that's fine because you must be aware that you're dealing with calls that are not (or close to) free from the context of the code.

...

It depends on the context of the code. If whenever you are accessing this property, you are sure you'll be reminded of the expensive call, then I think it is fine. But if that isn't the case, then you should make it more explicit by turning it into a full-blown method instead of a property.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your senior dev has missed the *asynchronous* nature of the code.  The only way to move your code to the getter of a property would be to block the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete and there is a value to return.  This would be very badly behaved property.

Answer (score 1):

He is correct about it being lazy-loaded in the accessor -- since the async call won't be made on object creation.  It will only be made when the accessor is called.

He is also anticipating not leaving it in the property accessor, but refactoring it elsewhere.  It is easier to refactor when the call is already isolated in the accessor.

It is however, not a good idea to leave the async call in the accessor, but it doesn't sound like he is expecting it to stay there.